# Is there a name for this type of layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, xamarin, textview

I am using Xamarin and am wanting to code a layout similar to this

[image]

Can someone please explain what type of layout this is so that I can find some example code, or even help me with some layout code so that I can create my own similar layout?

What type of layout is used, are the objects TextViews? If not, what type of objects are they? How do I setup the spacing between the objects etc?

Is there a generic name for this type of layout?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal android layout. You can implement this kind of ui using either Relative layout or Linear layout(if this is not a list). I would suggest to make 4 Linear layout orientation should be vertical so that you will get four containers for each card.

As far as style is concerned, each linear layout is given a card style. Googling about android card style will help you in implementing card style. 
[card layout](http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-make-an-android-card-list/)

Yes these are set of ImageView and TextView.
You can provide spacing either using margin or padding.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple Android Xml file which contains different LinearLayouts and RelativeLayouts if you have problem to make it in Xmarin then just create it in android eclipse or Adt and copy this layout and put in xmarin project...